# Magnetic field affects unwanted sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics, skfieldnode

I have a Player Sprite which moves as the user drag their finger across the screen. I have implemented a power that the player sprite creates a magnetic repulsive force around it.
My dilemma is that when the power is turned on the player sprite itself gets affect my it when it shouldn't be.

I have set the correct `fieldBitMask` and `categoryBitMask` on the desired sprites and the field node but still doesn't work.
This is my players physicsBody configuration:

```
physics.affectedByGravity = false
physics.allowsRotation = false
physics.dynamic = true;
sprite.physicsBody?.fieldBitMask = 0
```

Comment: This means nothing to us,  provide code that can actually recreate your error.  From what I can see, physics and physicsBody might be 2 different things, but that can't be told from this because you do not provide enough information.

Comment: Try to set player physics.dynamic = false

Comment: Thanks Simone, that worked!

Comment: @user2504879 you are welcome, I'll add as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **player node**:

```
physics.dynamic = false
```

Comment: This is a work around, it does not solve the problem.  Why would a player have a physics body, but not be dynamic.  @user2504879 is going to encounter more problems in the future with this (He may actually want the player sprite to by dynamic)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that worked. user2504879 : "Player Sprite which moves as the user drag their finger across the screen" may be his physics dynamic is not important. If is important, is correct to have more information about how the field is added to the sprite.

Comment: That is why I made my comment,  work around's should always be a last resort, and usually they should pertain to actual bugs that you can't fix.  In this case,  @user2504879 needs to provide more info if he/she wants the code to properly work.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon indeed player doesn't have to be dynamic when the SKFieldNode is active in the scene. After using it I turn player's physics back to physics.dynamic = true. It works perfectly

Comment: @user2504879 It works, it does not work perfectly. What are you going to do in the case of an object inside the magnetic field?  keep flopping back and forth?  You are going to keep implementing band aids to get around this problem, and eventually those band aids are going to be so unmanageable that you wll have to start all over.  You are better off learning how to do things the correct way, so that you do not have to worry about band aid fixes in the future.